# How to insert <p> tag in textfield when user hits "Enter" or "Return"?

Tags: html, css

In my app, a user can fill out certain information about him on his profile. For example I have an about section, where the user can write a paragraph about his life. Right now, if the user types anything and saves the input, it is shown as one paragraph. I want it so that if the user hits enter, it should add a `<p>` tag when it is displaying the content.

Update

Just look at this question for example. When I type a question and hit enter

this text appeared on a new line

this is what I want!

Comment: How do you update the `<p>` element? Show us some code.

Comment: Have you looked at using something like ckEditor? It would give your users styling options if you want them, plus it automatically creates the code for you, such as wrapping text in p tags.

Comment: They write in one big text box? And every time they enter a newline character, you want to surround in a <p> tag?

Comment: I assume you're sending this to some sort of backend? PHP? Java socket? That's where you need to do this processing

Comment: @pratski That "User enter info and saves" part is what you should show, the way you save this on the server side. This is not a HTML/CSS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to handle enter key.

Lets assume you are getting textarea value as a string `str`.

when you display it, just wrap every line with `<p>`

```
//`str` is textarea value
var str = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;

var lines = str.split(/\r?\n/);
// create html
var html="";
for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
    html+='<p>'+lines[i]+'</p>';
}

// use html here showing inside some div
var divEl = document.getElementById("myDiv");
divEL.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: How does stackoverflow do it? See you have 3 lines in your answer above. You pressed enter and a new line started

Comment: the HTML for your answer is `<p>You dont have to handle enter key.</p>`

Comment: If you have an ordinary <textarea>, without any javascript, then when you press enter a new line will be started (which is the behaviour you want). After the user is done typing you then, presumably, want to change the textarea lines into html. That's what this answer does.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are exactly asking for, but you can intercept the Enter key on inputs by doing such (with jquery).

```
$(".yourinputid").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // Manipulate the DOM
    }
});
```

I'm a bit confused about the `<p>` tag part. What do you want exactly to do?

Comment: See how in your answer, when you hit enter, the text is displayed on a new line. I want that

Comment: Is there not a keypressed event?

Answer (score -1):

Use `nl2br()` on POST value server-side (if on PHP; equivalents in other languages should be avaliable) or `String.replace()` on the textarea value client-side.